# Odd error when inserting Chatter post from Opportunity trigger

Tags: apex, unit-test, chatter, opportunity

I have a trigger on my Opportunity object that executes after insert and simply posts a new FeedItem to a specific group within my instance when the Opportunity record Stage is set to "Signed". Here is the method I'm calling to instantiate each FeedItem.

```
private FeedItem createSignedRecordPost(Opportunity o, String groupId)
{
    //create new feed item to insert
    FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
    post.ParentId = groupId;
    post.CreatedById = o.OwnerId;
    post.Body = 'BOOM! #InkBaby Put $'+ Math.round(o.SalesFundingAmount__c) +' on the board!';
    post.LinkUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + o.Id;
    post.Title = o.Name;

    return post;
}
```

After instantiating a list of FeedItems, I insert them at the end of my trigger logic.

Now, I have created the following unit test to test this logic:

```
static testMethod void recordSignedChatterPostTest()
{
    //create account
    Account a = new Account();
    a.Name = 'Test Account';
    insert a;

    //create contact
    Contact c = new Contact();
    c.FirstName = 'John';
    c.LastName = 'Doe';
    c.AccountId = a.Id;
    c.Phone = '1234567890';
    insert c;

    //create opportunity
    Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
    o.AccountId = a.Id;
    o.StageName = 'First Appointment';
    o.CloseDate = system.today();
    o.Name = 'Test Opp 1';
    insert o;

    //create primary contact record
    OpportunityContactRole cRole = new OpportunityContactRole();
    cRole.OpportunityId = o.Id;
    cRole.ContactId = c.Id;
    cRole.IsPrimary = true;
    cRole.Role = 'Decision Maker';
    insert cRole;

    //create chatter collaboration group
    CollaborationGroup[] chatterGroup = [SELECT Id FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Name='INKBABY' LIMIT 1];
    system.assertEquals(1, chatterGroup.size());

    Test.startTest();

    //update opportunity stagename to  'Signed'
    o.StageName = 'Signed';
    update o;

    Opportunity oppId = [SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :o.Id LIMIT 1];

    //new chatter feed item should have been added to the record
    FeedItem[] items = [SELECT Id, Title, ParentId FROM FeedItem WHERE CreatedDate=TODAY ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
    system.assertEquals(1, items.size(), 'There should only be one chatter post at this time.');

    //check that Stage Name is set to signed
    system.assertEquals(oppId.StageName, 'Signed');

    //assert that the feed post was posted to the ink baby group
    //system.assertEquals(inkBabyGroupId, items[0].ParentId);

    system.debug('--DEBUG-- Name and Title (should be the same) '+o.Name+ ', ' + items[0].Title);

    //assert that the feed post title is the name of the opportunity
    //system.assertEquals(o.Name, item.Title);

    Test.stopTest();
}
```

When I run this unit test I receive the following error:
**System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 006e0000002Wc6GAAS; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [CloseDate]: [CloseDate]**

As you can see in my unit test, I'm clearly setting the CloseDate of the Opportunity record. I'm really at a loss for words on this error. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Examine the unit test's debug log? I suspect you have a workflow or other "before / after update" trigger that might be clearing this field. Is this the only test that fails? Maybe something new was introduced recently that will make different Opp-related tests to fail...

Comment: Yeah I've looked into that very closely and the only thing that should effect the CloseDate is a WF I have to update it based on the current Stage of the Opportunity. I've double and triple checked to make sure the WF is working properly. I only receive the error when I attempt to create the Chatter post.

Comment: @eyescream agree .There is something nullifying the close date field .

Comment: Can you deactivate the workflow to rule out that is causing the issue?

Comment: It's only in the unit test or maybe also happens from GUI too? Any chance the way you calculate new date in this workflow might be getting a null somewhere? (null + 7 = null). Maybe workflow or your trigger fires twice (some side-effect that updates opp again)? Search in the log how many times name of trigger pops up.

Comment: Ok I was able to get past the error by modifying my WF rule to ensure there can never be a NULL value, and it seems to have alleviated the error. Now I'm running into an issue where the FeedPost unit test still isn't passing because it can't find the collaboration group id. I've tried recreating the CollaborationGroup within my unit test, but when I insert it, I get "Duplicate Value" error, saying a Group with that name already exists... Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(answer to latest issue from the comments thread ;))*

Interesting. So it can't find it but uniqueness check actually finds it? Hmm... Either use "@seeAllData=true" (nasty) or use different name for your group, maybe 'INKBABY Unit Test'.

Then in the test select correct group based either on `Test.isRunningTest()` or something like that:

```
CollaborationGroup[] chatterGroup = [SELECT Id 
FROM CollaborationGroup 
WHERE Name LIKE ='INKBABY%' 
ORDER BY Name ASC 
LIMIT 1];
```

Any kind of suffix to the group name will be skipped ;)

*(answer that kind of emerged from comments)*

Make sure that there are no workflows / triggers that clear the value of Close Date. If there's such workflow - make sure the formula it uses to determine new close date gets all arguments it needs. `null + 7 = null` so probably you have to specify more fields while inserting your Opportunity.

Comment: Went the route of changing the query to use the LIKE expression. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Follow up question: Any idea why it would work from the standard UI and not from a unit test, when essentially I was doing the exact same DML operation on the record...?

Comment: Could you post your "before and after" calculation that determines new CloseDate? Are you 100% positive all fields it relies on were filled in during Opp creation in the test (meaning that old formula didn't rely on say Amount field)?